# Fixed positioned div not applying @media rules when dragging width

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make a sidebar with variable width, but for some reason the @media rules are not triggering when changing manually the size of the bar:

[image]

In this simplifyed example, the background-color should change when the sidebar width is less than 350px, according to the following rule, but is not working, can't understand why

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 350px) {
            .sidebar {
                background-color: aqua;
            }
        }
```

Here it is a working code example:

```js
let sidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");
        let dragholder = document.querySelector(".dragholder");

        function onMouseMove(e) {
            sidebar.style.cssText = `width: ${ e.pageX }px`;
        }

        function onMouseDown(e) {
            document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
        }

        function onMouseUp(e) {
            document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
        }

        dragholder.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown);
        dragholder.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
```

```css
.sidebar {
            height: 100vh;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            background-color: #2D2D30;
            width: 450px;
            color: #FFF;
            padding: 5px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .dragholder {
            position: absolute;
            height: 100vh;
            width: 5px;
            background: yellow;
            right: -5px;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            border-radius: 80px;
        }

        .dragholder:hover {
            cursor: col-resize;
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 350px) {
            .sidebar {
                background-color: aqua;
            }
        }
```

```html
    <div class="sidebar"> TEST 123 
        <div class="dragholder"></div>
    </div>
```